# application runs from pycharm but not from command line (ModuleNotfounderror)

Tags: python, pycharm

I have app with the following folder tree:

```
MyApp
  |
  |-- Code
  |     |
  |     |-- main.py
  |     |-- settings.py
  |     |
  |-- vev
```

`venv` - is the virtual environment of that project.

I can run main.py from pycharm without any problem.

I'm trying to run it from command line:

1. I activate the `venv`
2. I run the following command from `MyApp` folder:

   python Code\main.py

and I'm getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Code'
```

How can I run `main.py` from command line (without any code change if it possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because pycharm usually sets PYTHONPATH for you.
To manually execute your code you need to set new PYTHONPATH variable.

On linux/mac it should be:
`export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`

And after this you should be able to run your code